# How can we write the function on definite integral form?

Tags: integration

How can we write the the following Stieltjes function on definite integral form?

$$\frac{1}{\log(1+x)}$$

for example :
$$\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{-1}}{x+t} dt $$

Comment: The definite integral with which bounds?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a primitive in terms of elemental functions. You might need to use numeric approximations

Comment: After a change of variables, you are asking about an antiderivative of $1/\log(x)$.  This does not have an antiderivative in terms of elementary functions.  This integral pops up enough that it even has its own special name: the [logarithmic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function).

Comment: Your example has left me more confused, rather than clarifying.  Your original question made me think that you were trying to find an antiderivative for $1/\log(x+1)$.  That is, you were looking for a "nice" way to evaluate $$ \int \frac{1}{\log(x+1)} \,\mathrm{d}x.$$  The answer to *that* question is "There isn't one."  But the example suggests that you are looking for something different.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: I think OP is essentially asking how to do like a "reverse Leibniz rule"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people have said in the comments,

$${\int\frac{1}{\log(1+x)}dx}$$

does not have an elementary antiderivative. However, judging by your edit - this is not what you are asking.

You want to write

$${\frac{1}{\log(1+x)}=\int_{a}^{b}f(x,t)dt}$$

for some function ${f(x,t)}$. Firstly, differentiate to get

$${\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{\log(1+x)}\right)=-\frac{1}{(1+x)\log^2(1+x)}}$$

Then clearly,

$${\frac{1}{\log(1+x)}=-\int_{\infty}^{x}\frac{1}{(1+t)\log^2(1+t)}dt=\int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+t)\log^2(1+t)}dt}$$

Now simply do ${u=\frac{t}{x}}$ to get

$${\Rightarrow \frac{1}{\log(1+x)}=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(1+xu)\log^2(1+xu)}du}$$

You can now rewrite in terms of ${x,t}$ just to make it look nicer ($u$ is just a dummy variable anyway)

$${\Rightarrow \frac{1}{\log(1+x)}=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(1+xt)\log^2(1+xt)}dt}$$

This is like a reverse Leibniz rule! (Or "Feynman trick" if you are a Physicist :P)

Answer (score 1):

Remember the first part of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: $$f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f'(t)dt$$